# pointInterval not working with date range within line chart

Tags: highcharts

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointInterval

[Chart - JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jainskumar7/0hndm6ja/)

I am trying to plot chart using with **pointInterval**, whenever I am passing x and y value into series data along with **plotOptions**, Granularity is not getting updated based on **pointInterval**.

````
  series: {
   pointStart: 1621366784000, // point start getting dynamic from data staring value
   pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // Granularity need to pass dynamically to plot chart
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

In API we can read:

> **pointInterval: number**
>
> If no x values are given for the points in a series, pointInterval
> defines the interval of the x values. For example, if a series
> contains one value every decade starting from year 0, set
> pointInterval to 10. In true datetime axes, the pointInterval is set
> in milliseconds. (...)

You can use `keys` property if you want to ignore `x` value:

```
    series: [{
        keys: ['', 'y'],
        data: [
            [1621366784000, 54],
            [1621368584000, 55],
            ...
        ]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rbmq2dyu/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.keys